# Why do I keep getting automatically logged out of control panel?

Tags: control-panel, ee4

I have never had this with older versions of EE but I just began working with the latest version, 4.3.6, and I keep getting automatically logged out of the control panel after saving changes to templates. I will click Save and wind up back at the login page. Sometimes when I attempt to log back in without refreshing the login page I get an error message "error: this form has expired. please refresh and try again."

I have found the proposed solutions to this problem for versions 2.X and have tried them but they have not worked. I have not seen any solutions specifically for the latest version.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to clean the cache of your web browser.

Comment: Thanks Stéphane. I have cleared the cache multiple times but that does not seem to help.

Comment: Try in Incognito mode (Private Window) of Browser.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out the solution that seems to be working for me was to add `$config[‘cp_session_type’] = “s”;` to my config.php file.

Although I don't know if this creates some type of security risk.